# Core translation override not working

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override: `vendor/magento/module_catalog/i18n/en_US.csv`

The file was copied to: `app/design/adminhtml/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/i18n/en_US.csv`

Then I ran: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f & php bin/magento cache:flush`

When I look at the admin area the label hasn't changed.

Comment: Did you created any custom theme for admin?

Comment: No I did not create an admin theme. I also tried putting the file here:

app/design/adminhtml/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Core Module translations will not be overridden in custom theme so you need to place the new translations in your custom module folder. Create an empty module or use your existing module.

Just Copy this file  **vendor/magento/module_catalog/i18n/en_US.csv** and paste it to any of your extension **app\code\vendor\module\i18n**

In detail, Go to section [Translation file is located in i18n folder](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-translation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try by keeping the file into:

```
app/design/adminhtml/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Currenlty you didn't put it in **i18n** directory. Also make sure that you have working admin theme which has already been created and configured. You can add the same translation using your custom module as translation is performed globally for whole area. It would be working fine for whole admin phrases.

Comment: I already had it in the i18n directory, I made a mistake when I posted this question and have it updated.